# T-SQL, concatenate strings while doing multiple join and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, inner-join

I wan't to concatenate all strings in a group, while doing a multiple join. Below is my scenario

Table - **log**

```
id | appname | level
---------------------
1  | app1    | debug
2  | app3    | warn
3  | app1    | debug
4  | app2    | info
```

Table - **log_tag**

```
id | text
----------
1  | tag_wink
2  | tag_steve
3  | ignore
4  | jimmy
```

Table - **log_tag_map**

```
tag_id | log_id
---------------
1      | 1
1      | 2
2      | 4
2      | 1
3      | 1
```

My goal is; For each log, join all it's tags separated by comma.

**This is my desired output**

```
id | appname | level | text
----------------------------
1  | app1    | debug | tag_wink, tag_steve, ignore
2  | app3    | warn  | tag_wink
3  | app1    | debug | 
4  | app2    | info  | tag_steve
```

I've bee trying a lot of things but can't seem to get the desired output.

This gives each log with a single tag_text

```
SELECT 
    log_table.id,
    log_table.appname,
    log_table.level,
    log_tag_table.text,
FROM log_table
INNER JOIN [log_tag_map] log_tag_map_table  
    ON log_tag_map_table.log_id = log_table.id
INNER JOIN [log_tag] log_tag_table 
    ON log_tag_map_table.tag_id = log_tag_table.id
ORDER BY log_table.id
```

After researching about concatenating strings in T-SQL, I used the famous ***FOR XML PATH*** solution, but I can't seem to get my desired result. I keep getting errors saying that "***log_tag_map_table.tag_id***" is invalid because it isn't in an aggregate function.

```
SELECT 
    log_table.id,
    MAX(log_table.appname),
    MAX(log_table.level),
    STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + [log_tag].text 
        FROM [log_tag] 
        WHERE
            log_tag_map_table.tag_id = log_tag.id AND 
            log_tag_map_table.log_id = log_table.id
        FOR XML PATH (''))
        , 1
        , 2
        , '')
FROM log_table
INNER JOIN [log_tag_map] log_tag_map_table  
    ON log_tag_map_table.log_id = log_table.id
INNER JOIN [log_tag] log_tag_table 
    ON log_tag_map_table.tag_id = log_tag_table.id
GROUP BY log_table.id
ORDER BY log_table.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix that by adding the renaming column's in `Group By`. The `Group by` in your query is just to remove the duplicates.

I prefer `APPLY` operator over `correlated-sub-query`. It looks simple and removal of *leading* or *trailing* `comma` is very easy

```
SELECT DISTINCT log_table.id,
                log_table.appname,
                log_table.level,
                LEFT(concat_text, Len(concat_text) - 1) as Concat_text
FROM   log_table
       OUTER apply (SELECT [log_tag].text + ','
                    FROM   [log_tag_map] log_tag_map_table
                           JOIN log_tag
                             ON log_tag_map_table.tag_id = log_tag.id
                    WHERE  log_tag_map_table.log_id = log_table.id
                    FOR XML PATH ('')) oa (concat_text) 
ORDER BY log_table.id
```

**Demo :**

**Schema Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE log_table
  (
     [id]      INT,
     [appname] VARCHAR(4),
     [level]   VARCHAR(5)
  );

CREATE TABLE log_tag
  (
     [id]   INT,
     [text] VARCHAR(9)
  );

CREATE TABLE log_tag_map
  (
     [tag_id] INT,
     [log_id] INT
  );
```

**Sample data**

```
INSERT INTO log_table
            ([id],[appname],[level])
VALUES      (1,'app1','debug'),
            (2,'app3','warn'),
            (3,'app1','debug'),
            (4,'app2','info');


INSERT INTO log_tag
            ([id],[text])
VALUES      (1,'tag_wink'),
            (2,'tag_steve'),
            (3,'ignore'),
            (4,'jimmy');



INSERT INTO log_tag_map
            ([tag_id],[log_id])
VALUES      (1,1),
            (1,2),
            (2,4),
            (2,1),
            (3,1);
```

**Query :**

```
SELECT DISTINCT log_table.id,
                log_table.appname,
                log_table.level,
                LEFT(concat_text, Len(concat_text) - 1) as Concat_Text
FROM   log_table
       OUTER apply (SELECT [log_tag].text + ','
                    FROM   [log_tag_map] log_tag_map_table
                           JOIN log_tag
                             ON log_tag_map_table.tag_id = log_tag.id
                    WHERE  log_tag_map_table.log_id = log_table.id
                    FOR XML PATH ('')) oa (concat_text) 
Order by log_table.id
```

**Reuslt :**

```
╔════╦═════════╦═══════╦═══════════════════════════╗
║ id ║ appname ║ level ║        Concat_Text        ║
╠════╬═════════╬═══════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ app1    ║ debug ║ tag_wink,tag_steve,ignore ║
║  2 ║ app3    ║ warn  ║ tag_wink                  ║
║  3 ║ app1    ║ debug ║ NULL                      ║
║  4 ║ app2    ║ info  ║ tag_steve                 ║
╚════╩═════════╩═══════╩═══════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Tried this,but still not providing the desired output (all text concatenated with ", ").

Comment: Thanks, the updated query seems to get the job done. Gotta get my head over thinking that Join will solve all my problem.

Answer (score 0):

here is the way using `STUFF`.

```
SELECT  log_table.id,
        log_table.appname,
        log_table.level,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + [log_tag].text [text()]
         FROM [log_tag_map] log_tag_map_table
                           JOIN log_tag
                             ON log_tag_map_table.tag_id = log_tag.id
                    WHERE  log_tag_map_table.log_id = log_table.id
         FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,' ') text
FROM log_table
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

You will also get the OP using `CROSS APPLY`.

```
SELECT  Id ,appname,level,[text]
FROM    (
        SELECT   log_table.id,
        log_table.appname,
        log_table.level
        FROM    log_table
        ) a
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [log_tag].text) WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE ', ' END +[log_tag].text [text()]
        FROM [log_tag_map] log_tag_map_table
                           JOIN log_tag
                             ON log_tag_map_table.tag_id = log_tag.id
                    WHERE  log_tag_map_table.log_id = a.id
        ORDER BY
                [log_tag].text
        FOR XML PATH ('')
        ) b([text])
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]